# Getting segmentation fault with function calls?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am trying to debug some code I wrote for creating a Fibonacci sphere and using the [Bowyer-Watson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowyer%E2%80%93Watson_algorithm) to triangulate the points plotted. I kept getting seg faults so I decided to use this [online C debugger](https://www.onlinegdb.com) to try and solve it. And I keep getting seg faults and I can't seem to fix it.

Here is my implementation of the triangulation algorithm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// uses the Bowyer-Watson algorithm to implement Delaunay triangulation
// which triangulates the points just plotted, to form the Fibonacci sphere

// vertex struct
typedef struct Vertex
{
    // x and y coordinates of vertex
    double x;
    double y;
}vertex;

// compare the vertices
int vertex_equals(vertex v1, vertex v2)
{
    return v1.x == v2.x && v1.y == v2.y;
}

// edge struct
typedef struct Edge
{
    // the two vertices that make up the starting and ending vertex of the edge
    vertex v0;
    vertex v1;
}edge;

// compare one edge to another
int edge_equals(edge e1, edge e2)
{
    return (vertex_equals(e1.v0, e2.v0) && vertex_equals(e1.v1, e2.v1)) ||
        (vertex_equals(e1.v0, e2.v1) && vertex_equals(e1.v1, e2.v0));
}

// circumcircle struct
typedef struct Circumcircle
{
    // the center of the circle
    vertex c;
    // radius
    double r;
}circum_circ;

// triangle struct
typedef struct Triangle
{
    // takes three vertices to make a triangle
    vertex v0;
    vertex v1;
    vertex v2;
    // along with the circumcircle, to set the boundaries of each triangle
    circum_circ circumcirc;
}triangle;

// function that calculates the circumcircle (copy and pasted cuz idk what this is tbh)
circum_circ calc_circum_circ(vertex v0, vertex v1, vertex v2)
{
    double A = v1.x - v0.x;
    double B = v1.y - v0.y;
    double C = v2.x - v0.x;
    double D = v2.y - v0.y;

    double E = A * (v0.x + v1.x) + B * (v0.y + v1.y);
    double F = C * (v0.x + v2.x) + D * (v0.y + v2.y);

    double G = 2.0 * (A * (v2.y - v1.y) - B * (v2.x - v1.x));

    double dx, dy;
    vertex center;
    double radius;

    // Collinear points, get extremes and use midpoint as center
    if (round(fabs(G)) == 0)
    {
        double minx = fmin(v0.x, fmin(v1.x, v2.x));
        double miny = fmin(v0.y, fmin(v1.y, v2.y));
        double maxx = fmax(v0.x, fmax(v1.x, v2.x));
        double maxy = fmax(v0.y, fmax(v1.y, v2.y));

        center.x = (minx + maxx) / 2;
        center.y = (miny + maxy) / 2;

        dx = center.x - minx;
        dy = center.y - miny;
    }
    else
    {
        double cx = (D * E - B * F) / G;
        double cy = (A * F - C * E) / G;

        center.x = cx;
        center.y = cy;

        dx = center.x - v0.x;
        dy = center.y - v0.y;
    }
    radius = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    circum_circ circle = {center, radius};
    return circle;
}

// makes triangle
triangle make_triangle(vertex v0, vertex v1, vertex v2)
{
    // initialize triangle and assigns input to compute
    triangle t;
    t.v0 = v0;
    t.v1 = v1;
    t.v2 = v2;
    // takes the triangle points and uses that to calculate circumcircle for that triangle
    t.circumcirc = calc_circum_circ(v0, v1, v2);
    // return triangle
    return t;
}

// check to see if a given vertex is in the circumcircle or not
int in_circumcircle(triangle t, vertex v)
{
    // get the distance between the given circumcircle and the given vertex
    // on the x and y axis
    double dx = t.circumcirc.c.x - v.x;
    double dy = t.circumcirc.c.y - v.y;
    // return the overall distance between the x and y axis distance and the radius of the circle
    return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= t.circumcirc.r;
}

// the super triangle canvases most (if not all) points in the scene
// to encapsulate all the vertices we're working on right now
triangle make_super_triangle(vertex* vertices, int num_vertices)
{
    double minx = INFINITY, miny = INFINITY, maxx = -INFINITY, maxy = -INFINITY;
    for(int i=0; i<num_vertices; i++)
    {
        // tries to avoid seg fault here
        if(num_vertices > 0)
        {
            if(vertices[i].x < minx) minx = vertices[i].x;
            if(vertices[i].y < miny) miny = vertices[i].y;
            if(vertices[i].x > maxx) maxx = vertices[i].x;
            if(vertices[i].y > maxy) maxy = vertices[i].y;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Vertex struct not accessible\n");
        }
    }

    double dx = (maxx - minx) * 10;
    double dy = (maxy - miny) * 10;

    vertex v0 = {minx - dx, miny - dy * 3};
    vertex v1 = {minx - dx, maxy + dy};
    vertex v2 = {maxx + dx * 3, maxy + dy};

    return make_triangle(v0, v1, v2);
}

// update array of triangles by adding new vertex
triangle* add_vertex(vertex v, triangle* triangles, int* num_triangles)
{
    edge edges[3];
    int num_edges = 0;

    // remove triangles with circumcircles containing the vertex
    for(int i = 0; i < *num_triangles; i++)
    {
        if(in_circumcircle(triangles[i], v))
        {
            edges[num_edges++] = (edge){triangles[i].v0, triangles[i].v1};
            edges[num_edges++] = (edge){triangles[i].v1, triangles[i].v2};
            edges[num_edges++] = (edge){triangles[i].v2, triangles[i].v0};
            triangles[i] = triangles[--(*num_triangles)];
            i--;
        }
    }

    // get unique edges
    edge unique_edges[num_edges];
    int num_unique_edges = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_edges; i++)
    {
        // uniqueness flag
        int is_unique = 1;

        // see if edge is unique
        for(int i = 0; i < num_edges; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < num_edges; j++)
            {
                // if not unique stop
                if(i != j && edge_equals(edges[i], edges[j]))
                {
                    is_unique = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // edge is unique, add to unique edges array
            if(is_unique)
            {
                unique_edges[num_unique_edges++] = edges[i];
            }
        }
        // create new triangles from the unique edges and new vertex
        triangle* new_triangles = (triangle*)malloc(sizeof(triangle) * num_unique_edges);

        // try to catch seg fault
        if(new_triangles == NULL)
        {
            free(new_triangles);
            return NULL;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < num_unique_edges; i++)
        {
            new_triangles[i] = make_triangle(unique_edges[i].v0, unique_edges[i].v1, v);
        }

        // append new triangles to triangle array
        triangle* result = (triangle*)realloc(triangles, sizeof(triangle) * (*num_triangles + num_unique_edges));
        // again, try to catch seg fault
        if(result == NULL)
        {
            free(new_triangles);
            return NULL;
        }

        triangles = result;
        for(int i=0; i < num_unique_edges; i++)
        {
            triangles[(*num_triangles)++] = new_triangles[i];
        }
        free(new_triangles);
        return triangles;
    }
    return triangles;
}

// finally, after everything, we triangulate the points
triangle* triangulate(vertex* vertices, int num_vertices, int* num_triangles)
{
    // create bounding 'super' triangle
    triangle st = make_super_triangle(vertices, num_vertices);

    // initialize triangles while adding bounding triangle
    triangle* triangles = (triangle*)malloc(sizeof(triangle));
    if(triangles == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    triangles[0] = st;
    *num_triangles = 1;

    // triangulate each vertex
    for(int i=0; i < num_vertices; i++)
    {
        triangles = add_vertex(vertices[i], triangles, num_triangles);
        // catch seg fault
        if(triangles == NULL)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    // remove triangles that share edges with super triangle
    for(int i = 0; i < *num_triangles; i++)
    {
        if (vertex_equals(triangles[i].v0, st.v0) || vertex_equals(triangles[i].v0, st.v1) || vertex_equals(triangles[i].v0, st.v2) ||
            vertex_equals(triangles[i].v1, st.v0) || vertex_equals(triangles[i].v1, st.v1) || vertex_equals(triangles[i].v1, st.v2) ||
            vertex_equals(triangles[i].v2, st.v0) || vertex_equals(triangles[i].v2, st.v1) || vertex_equals(triangles[i].v2, st.v2)) {
            triangles[i] = triangles[--(*num_triangles)];
            i--;
    }

    // resize triangles array
    //free(triangles);
    triangle* result = (triangle*)realloc(triangles, sizeof(triangle) * (*num_triangles));
    if(result == NULL)
    {
        free(triangles);
        return NULL;
    }
    triangles = result;

    return triangles;
    }
    return triangles;
}
```

```
void create_fibonacci_sphere(int radius, int num_of_points, float points[][3], size_t arr_size)
{
    // step 1: using the golden ratio and angle increments, plot out the points of the sphere
    double golden_ratio = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2;
    double angle_increment = 2 * M_PI * golden_ratio;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_points; ++i)
    {
        double t = (double)i / num_of_points;
        double angle1 = acos(1 - 2 * t);
        double angle2 = angle_increment * i;

        points[i][0] = radius * sin(angle1) * cos(angle2);
        points[i][1] = radius * sin(angle1) * sin(angle2);
        points[i][2] = radius * cos(angle1);
    }

    // step 2: using a C adaption of the Bowyer-Watson algorithm for Delaunay triangulations,
    // link up the points as triangles, effectively stitching together the sphere
        vertex point_list[num_of_points];
        for (int n = 0; n < num_of_points; n++)
        {
            if(n <= num_of_points)
            {
                point_list[n] = (vertex) {points[n][0], points[n][1]};
                point_list[n] = (vertex) {points[n][0], points[n][2]};
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Access denied.\n");
            }
        }

        int num_triangles;
        triangle* triangles = triangulate(point_list, arr_size, &num_triangles);
        // print out the triangulated coordinates
        for (int i = 0; i < num_triangles; ++i)
        {
            printf("%f %f %f %f %f %f\n", triangles[i].v0.x, triangles[i].v0.y,
                   triangles[i].v1.x, triangles[i].v1.y,
                   triangles[i].v2.x, triangles[i].v2.y);
        }

        free(triangles);

    }
    printf("%d points generated on Fibonacci sphere with radius %d.\n", num_of_points, radius);

}
```

```
int main(void)
{
    int radius = 50;
    int num_of_points = 1000;
    float vertices[num_of_points][3];
    create_fibonacci_sphere(radius, num_of_points, vertices, sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(vertices[0]));

    printf("this will print if there are no errors.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Something weird indentation-wise is going on at "step 2". Where's the opening `{` for that block?

Comment: If you get a segfault like that the first thing to check is that `n` is in range of both elements.

Comment: There's also an an apparently duplicated assignment there where you assign, then immediately stomp with entirely different values.

Comment: Since you already know the size of the array, there's no need for clutter like `sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(vertices[0])`. This is reverse-engineering what you specified literally a line above.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on. It can be especially hard to figure out code *and* what the indentation is saying at the same time.

Comment: The indentation is especially misleading in your `triangulate` function where that `if` looks like it wraps the `for`, which it absolutely does not.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind here is when trying to solve problems like this it really helps if you have functions you can call in a unit test where there are well-defined inputs and well-defined outputs. Trying to test the thing in one shot like this is way harder and will require a lot more patience and attention. Keep your code as dumb as possible, and write tests to ensure it all works as expected under the required conditions before moving to integrate it with other code. There are a number of popular unit test tools for C which I'd encourage you to explore.

Comment: This looks very wrong: `// resize triangles array    free(triangles); triangle* result = (triangle*)realloc(triangles, sizeof(triangles) * (*num_triangles));` You should not `free()` then `realloc()`, you should just `realloc()`.

Comment: I also suspect you really meant `realloc(triangles, sizeof(triangle) * (*num_triangles));`. The difference is hard to spot, but `triangle` seems likely be be a structure type, and `triangles` is a pointer variable. I always like to append `_t` to types I make, so it is obvious, e.g. `triangle_t`.

Comment: 300 lines isn't that much code. We would like an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For C, we'd like a _single_ `.c` file [_with_ (e.g.) `#include <stdio.h>`]. But, _no_ (e.g.) `#include "myprogram.h"`. For runtime errors, it should compile cleanly. We should be able to download it and build and run it on our local systems [if we so choose].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps I took to debug:

I ran the program under `gdb`. In `add_vertex`, it aborted in the first `for` loop on:

```
triangles[i] = triangles[--(*num_triangles)];
```

Either `i` or `*num_triangles` would have random/crazy values.

I added a debug `printf` to the loop to print `i` at the top of the loop. It came up clean. So, this meant that somewhere *within* that loop iteration might be the problem

I rebuilt with `-fsanitize=address`. The address sanitizer complained about `edges`:

```
  This frame has 1 object(s):
    [32, 128) 'edges'
```

This indicated to me that an index into `edges` was overflowing. So, I added an explicit check for that *before* actually allowing access to `edges`.

The definition:

```
edge edges[3];
```

The above check caught the fact that `num_edges` could exceed `3`.

It wants to add 3 new edges *per loop iteration*. The [maximum] number of loop iterations is: `*num_triangles`.

So, `edges` is too small. It *should* be:

```
edge edges[*num_triangles * 3];
```

---

Here is the corrected code. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#if DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

#define sysfault(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        printf(_fmt); \
        _sysfault(); \
    } while (0)

void
_sysfault(void)
{

    exit(1);
}

#define ARRAY_COUNT(_arr) \
    (sizeof(_arr) / sizeof(_arr[0]))

// uses the Bowyer-Watson algorithm to implement Delaunay triangulation
// which triangulates the points just plotted, to form the Fibonacci sphere

// vertex struct
typedef struct Vertex {
    // x and y coordinates of vertex
    double x;
    double y;
} vertex;

// compare the vertices
int
vertex_equals(vertex v1, vertex v2)
{
    return v1.x == v2.x && v1.y == v2.y;
}

// edge struct
typedef struct Edge {
    // the two vertices that make up the starting and ending vertex of the edge
    vertex v0;
    vertex v1;
} edge;

// compare one edge to another
int
edge_equals(edge e1, edge e2)
{
    return (vertex_equals(e1.v0, e2.v0) && vertex_equals(e1.v1, e2.v1)) || (vertex_equals(e1.v0, e2.v1) && vertex_equals(e1.v1, e2.v0));
}

// circumcircle struct
typedef struct Circumcircle {
    // the center of the circle
    vertex c;
    // radius
    double r;
} circum_circ;

// triangle struct
typedef struct Triangle {
    // takes three vertices to make a triangle
    vertex v0;
    vertex v1;
    vertex v2;
    // along with the circumcircle, to set the boundaries of each triangle
    circum_circ circumcirc;
} triangle;

// function that calculates the circumcircle (copy and pasted cuz idk what this is tbh)
circum_circ
calc_circum_circ(vertex v0, vertex v1, vertex v2)
{
    double A = v1.x - v0.x;
    double B = v1.y - v0.y;
    double C = v2.x - v0.x;
    double D = v2.y - v0.y;

    double E = A * (v0.x + v1.x) + B * (v0.y + v1.y);
    double F = C * (v0.x + v2.x) + D * (v0.y + v2.y);

    double G = 2.0 * (A * (v2.y - v1.y) - B * (v2.x - v1.x));

    double dx,
     dy;
    vertex center;
    double radius;

    // Collinear points, get extremes and use midpoint as center
    if (round(fabs(G)) == 0) {
        double minx = fmin(v0.x, fmin(v1.x, v2.x));
        double miny = fmin(v0.y, fmin(v1.y, v2.y));
        double maxx = fmax(v0.x, fmax(v1.x, v2.x));
        double maxy = fmax(v0.y, fmax(v1.y, v2.y));

        center.x = (minx + maxx) / 2;
        center.y = (miny + maxy) / 2;

        dx = center.x - minx;
        dy = center.y - miny;
    }
    else {
        double cx = (D * E - B * F) / G;
        double cy = (A * F - C * E) / G;

        center.x = cx;
        center.y = cy;

        dx = center.x - v0.x;
        dy = center.y - v0.y;
    }
    radius = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    circum_circ circle = { center, radius };
    return circle;
}

// makes triangle
triangle
make_triangle(vertex v0, vertex v1, vertex v2)
{
    // initialize triangle and assigns input to compute
    triangle t;

    t.v0 = v0;
    t.v1 = v1;
    t.v2 = v2;
    // takes the triangle points and uses that to calculate circumcircle for that triangle
    t.circumcirc = calc_circum_circ(v0, v1, v2);
    // return triangle
    return t;
}

// check to see if a given vertex is in the circumcircle or not
int
in_circumcircle(triangle t, vertex v)
{
    // get the distance between the given circumcircle and the given vertex
    // on the x and y axis
    double dx = t.circumcirc.c.x - v.x;
    double dy = t.circumcirc.c.y - v.y;

    // return the overall distance between the x and y axis distance and the radius of the circle
    return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= t.circumcirc.r;
}

// the super triangle canvases most (if not all) points in the scene
// to encapsulate all the vertices we're working on right now
triangle
make_super_triangle(vertex *vertices, int num_vertices)
{
    double minx = INFINITY,
        miny = INFINITY,
        maxx = -INFINITY,
        maxy = -INFINITY;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_vertices; i++) {
        // tries to avoid seg fault here
        if (num_vertices > 0) {
            if (vertices[i].x < minx)
                minx = vertices[i].x;
            if (vertices[i].y < miny)
                miny = vertices[i].y;
            if (vertices[i].x > maxx)
                maxx = vertices[i].x;
            if (vertices[i].y > maxy)
                maxy = vertices[i].y;
        }
        else {
            printf("Vertex struct not accessible\n");
        }
    }

    double dx = (maxx - minx) * 10;
    double dy = (maxy - miny) * 10;

    vertex v0 = { minx - dx, miny - dy * 3 };
    vertex v1 = { minx - dx, maxy + dy };
    vertex v2 = { maxx + dx * 3, maxy + dy };

    return make_triangle(v0, v1, v2);
}

// update array of triangles by adding new vertex
triangle *
add_vertex(vertex v, triangle *triangles, int *num_triangles)
{
// NOTE/BUG: this is fixed bug it can be indexed up to num_triangles - 1
#if BUG
    edge edges[3];
#else
    edge edges[*num_triangles * 3];
#endif
    int num_edges = 0;

    dbgprt("add_vertex: ENTER num_triangles=%d\n",*num_triangles);

    // remove triangles with circumcircles containing the vertex
    for (int i = 0; i < *num_triangles; i++) {
        dbgprt("add_vertex: LOOP i=%d\n",i);

        if (in_circumcircle(triangles[i], v)) {
// NOTE/FIX: check for overflow
#if ! BUG
            if ((num_edges + 3) >= ARRAY_COUNT(edges))
                sysfault("add_vertex: fault -- num_edges=%d MAX=%zu\n",
                    num_edges,ARRAY_COUNT(edges));
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: when edges is overflowed here, it _corrupts_ the value of i ...
            edges[num_edges++] = (edge) { triangles[i].v0, triangles[i].v1};
            edges[num_edges++] = (edge) { triangles[i].v1, triangles[i].v2};
            edges[num_edges++] = (edge) { triangles[i].v2, triangles[i].v0};

// NOTE/BUG: trying to dereference with the corrupt value of i causes the
// segfault
            triangles[i] = triangles[--(*num_triangles)];
            i--;
        }
    }

    // get unique edges
    edge unique_edges[num_edges];
    int num_unique_edges = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_edges; i++) {
        // uniqueness flag
        int is_unique = 1;

        // see if edge is unique
        for (int i = 0; i < num_edges; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < num_edges; j++) {
                // if not unique stop
                if (i != j && edge_equals(edges[i], edges[j])) {
                    is_unique = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // edge is unique, add to unique edges array
            if (is_unique) {
                unique_edges[num_unique_edges++] = edges[i];
            }
        }
        // create new triangles from the unique edges and new vertex
        triangle *new_triangles = malloc(sizeof(triangle) * num_unique_edges);

        // try to catch seg fault
        if (new_triangles == NULL) {
            free(new_triangles);
            return NULL;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num_unique_edges; i++)
            new_triangles[i] = make_triangle(unique_edges[i].v0, unique_edges[i].v1, v);

        // append new triangles to triangle array
        triangle *result = realloc(triangles,
                sizeof(triangle) * (*num_triangles + num_unique_edges));
        if (result == NULL) {
#if 0
            free(new_triangles);
#else
            sysfault("realloc/result\n");
#endif
            return NULL;
        }

        triangles = result;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_unique_edges; i++) {
            triangles[(*num_triangles)++] = new_triangles[i];
        }

        free(new_triangles);
        return triangles;
    }

    return triangles;
}

// finally, after everything, we triangulate the points
triangle *
triangulate(vertex *vertices, int num_vertices, int *num_triangles)
{
    // create bounding 'super' triangle
    triangle st = make_super_triangle(vertices, num_vertices);

    // initialize triangles while adding bounding triangle
    triangle *triangles = (triangle *) malloc(sizeof(triangle));

    if (triangles == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    triangles[0] = st;
    *num_triangles = 1;

    // triangulate each vertex
    for (int i = 0; i < num_vertices; i++) {
        triangles = add_vertex(vertices[i], triangles, num_triangles);
        // catch seg fault
        if (triangles == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    // remove triangles that share edges with super triangle
    for (int i = 0; i < *num_triangles; i++) {
        if (vertex_equals(triangles[i].v0, st.v0) || vertex_equals(triangles[i].v0, st.v1) || vertex_equals(triangles[i].v0, st.v2) || vertex_equals(triangles[i].v1, st.v0) || vertex_equals(triangles[i].v1, st.v1) || vertex_equals(triangles[i].v1, st.v2) || vertex_equals(triangles[i].v2, st.v0) || vertex_equals(triangles[i].v2, st.v1) || vertex_equals(triangles[i].v2, st.v2)) {
            triangles[i] = triangles[--(*num_triangles)];
            i--;
        }

        // resize triangles array
        // free(triangles);
        triangle *result = (triangle *) realloc(triangles, sizeof(triangle) * (*num_triangles));

        if (result == NULL) {
            free(triangles);
            return NULL;
        }
        triangles = result;

        return triangles;
    }
    return triangles;
}

void
create_fibonacci_sphere(int radius, int num_of_points, float points[][3], size_t arr_size)
{
    // step 1: using the golden ratio and angle increments, plot out the points of the sphere
    double golden_ratio = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2;
    double angle_increment = 2 * M_PI * golden_ratio;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_points; ++i) {
        double t = (double) i / num_of_points;
        double angle1 = acos(1 - 2 * t);
        double angle2 = angle_increment * i;

        points[i][0] = radius * sin(angle1) * cos(angle2);
        points[i][1] = radius * sin(angle1) * sin(angle2);
        points[i][2] = radius * cos(angle1);
    }

    // step 2: using a C adaption of the Bowyer-Watson algorithm for Delaunay triangulations,
    // link up the points as triangles, effectively stitching together the sphere
    vertex point_list[num_of_points];

    for (int n = 0; n < num_of_points; n++) {
        if (n <= num_of_points) {
            point_list[n] = (vertex) {
            points[n][0], points[n][1]};
            point_list[n] = (vertex) {
            points[n][0], points[n][2]};
        }
        else {
            printf("Access denied.\n");
        }
    }

    int num_triangles;
    triangle *triangles = triangulate(point_list, arr_size, &num_triangles);

    // print out the triangulated coordinates
    for (int i = 0; i < num_triangles; ++i) {
        printf("%f %f %f %f %f %f\n", triangles[i].v0.x, triangles[i].v0.y, triangles[i].v1.x, triangles[i].v1.y, triangles[i].v2.x, triangles[i].v2.y);
    }

    free(triangles);

    printf("%d points generated on Fibonacci sphere with radius %d.\n", num_of_points, radius);

}

int
main(void)
{
    int radius = 50;
    int num_of_points = 1000;
    float vertices[num_of_points][3];

    create_fibonacci_sphere(radius, num_of_points, vertices, sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(vertices[0]));

    printf("this will print if there are no errors.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if BUG
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if FIX
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k -UBUG`

---

Here is the program output after the fix:

```
18.061037 46.599998 -1048.077412 1049.000015 22.768284 44.500000
0.390589 49.799999 3044.524433 1049.000015 3.327554 49.700001
-1048.077412 1049.000015 -2.330599 49.900002 -6.215407 49.599998
5.951316 49.500000 -1048.077412 1049.000015 8.367871 49.200001
8.367871 49.200001 -1048.077412 1049.000015 11.063197 48.700001
3044.524433 1049.000015 5.951316 49.500000 8.367871 49.200001
-8.729562 49.099998 -6.757220 48.599998 -1.562079 48.500000
11.063197 48.700001 -8.729562 49.099998 -1.562079 48.500000
-6.757220 48.599998 3.121604 48.900002 -1.562079 48.500000
-12.916064 48.299999 -6.215407 49.599998 -8.969928 48.000000
3044.524433 1049.000015 8.367871 49.200001 11.063197 48.700001
-8.969928 48.000000 -8.729562 49.099998 -12.040624 47.799999
-6.215407 49.599998 -9.420875 48.799999 -6.757220 48.599998
-9.420875 48.799999 3.121604 48.900002 -6.757220 48.599998
3.121604 48.900002 -6.215407 49.599998 -1.562079 48.500000
-1048.077412 1049.000015 -6.215407 49.599998 -12.916064 48.299999
-12.916064 48.299999 -8.969928 48.000000 -12.040624 47.799999
11.063197 48.700001 -1048.077412 1049.000015 14.210360 47.900002
-6.215407 49.599998 -6.757220 48.599998 -5.583539 47.200001
3044.524433 1049.000015 11.063197 48.700001 14.210360 47.900002
-8.729562 49.099998 -12.916064 48.299999 -12.040624 47.799999
-8.969928 48.000000 -6.215407 49.599998 -6.257406 47.299999
-8.729562 49.099998 -8.969928 48.000000 -6.257406 47.299999
-6.215407 49.599998 -8.729562 49.099998 -6.257406 47.299999
14.210360 47.900002 -1048.077412 1049.000015 18.061037 46.599998
3044.524433 1049.000015 14.210360 47.900002 18.061037 46.599998
-1048.077412 1049.000015 3044.524433 1049.000015 22.768284 44.500000
3044.524433 1049.000015 18.061037 46.599998 22.768284 44.500000
1000 points generated on Fibonacci sphere with radius 50.
this will print if there are no errors.
```

---

Although it *is* legal to pass a `struct` *by value* to a function, this is almost never done. Much better to pass *by reference* (i.e. by *pointer*).

This is because passing by value does *lots* of *unnecessary* copying, so the program runs slowly.

Also, it doesn't *scale*. If a struct had (e.g.):

```
int data[10000000];
```

as a member, passing by value would cause a segfault due to stack overflow.

So, as an example, here is how I would change one such instance:

```
// check to see if a given vertex is in the circumcircle or not
int
in_circumcircle(const triangle *t, const vertex *v)
{
    // get the distance between the given circumcircle and the given vertex
    // on the x and y axis
    double dx = t->circumcirc.c.x - v->x;
    double dy = t->circumcirc.c.y - v->y;

    // return the overall distance between the x and y axis distance and the radius of the circle
    return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= t->circumcirc.r;
}
```

And, in `add_vertex`, I'd call it with:

```
if (in_circumcircle(&triangles[i], &v)) {
```

Further, *returning* a `struct` by value is even worse as it must:

1. The *caller* function must make room on the stack for the return value.
2. The *called* function must have create the value in its stack frame
3. The *called* function, at the return point, must copy from its stack frame to the caller's temp area on the stack
4. The *caller* function must copy from that temp area into the final place for the struct value

Here is how I would refactor `make_triangle`:

```
// makes triangle
void
make_triangle(triangle *t,const vertex *v0, const vertex *v1, const vertex *v2)
{

    // initialize triangle and assigns input to compute
    t->v0 = *v0;
    t->v1 = *v1;
    t->v2 = *v2;

    // takes the triangle points and uses that to calculate circumcircle for
    // that triangle
    t->circumcirc = calc_circum_circ(v0, v1, v2);
}
```