# Is it OK to return a struct in a C function, or is it better to return a pointer to a struct created with malloc()

Tags: c, function, struct, return-type

Both options are legal, but which one is better or "cleaner" :

Suppose we have this structure:

```
typedef struct MyStruct {
int val;
} MyStruct;
```

1st option; returning directly a struct:

```
MyStruct Create()
{
MyStruct a;
a.val = 0;
return a;
}
```

2nd option: creating the struct on the heap and returning a pointer:

```
MyStruct* CreatePtr()
{
MyStruct *a = (MyStruct*)malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
a->val = 0;
return a;
}
```

I think that the best choice depends on the size of the struct but maybe they are more things to take into account ?

Comment: In many cases, they will be optimized into essentially the same code.

Comment: One note is that the second form allows for `MyStruct` to be opaque, and to change its size without breaking binary compatibility.  That may or may not be relevant for your use case.

Comment: ["How long is a piece of string?"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/how-long-is-a-piece-of-string) It depends on the size of the `struct`. If it is large, it's more efficient to use pointer to a single copy.

Comment: @NateEldredge Good to know about the compiler optimization, so in this case it would be better to return the whole struct as the writing is more "clean" and readable, imo. However, regarding your second point, what do you mean by "binary compatibility" ?

Comment: @WeatherVane Ok so, if we ignore compiler optimizations as I read in the other question, size is the most important parameter to take into account. I agree that "large" is quite vague and depends on the context/applications/ressources.

Comment: I am going against the trend, but I was taught not to let the compiler do the work for me. Coming to C from assembler allowed me to (originally) write code more easily and still keep control of it. And I still do that: find an optimal solution, and then let the compiler improve it. I am not a fan of throwing a rubbish solution at the compiler and saying "Heck the compiler will generate the same code anyway." IMO it's only one step short from asking an AI to *gimme the codes*.

Comment: @Wheatley - One potential problem with the second solution is that someone has to remember to free the pointer when done with the struct.

Comment: There is third option: pass pointer to a struct as function argument.

Comment: I've rarely [if ever] used pass-by-value for a struct. Only if it's a "smart pointer" (e.g.) `typedef struct { struct realdata *ptr; int refcount; } handle_t;` See my answer: [Getting segmentation fault with function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76503043/5382650)

Answer (score 5):

As a rule of thumb, use the stack unless there is some good reason to put the struct on the heap. In general, always be as direct as possible in how you describe your intentions to the compiler, so that it can do the best job possible — check out the return-value optimisation for what will probably happen if you just pass on the stack; in all probability the result struct will be built directly in the storage of the caller, avoiding the call stack entirely (subject to caveats).

We’re a long way away from the era of avoiding straight’s phrasings just for the sake of good compilation.

If you have a specific reason that this is a concern, profile and optimise from there.

Comment: I was not aware of the return-value optimisation, I will have a look at it thank you.
I don't have any specific reason right now, it is quite a "theoretical" question. I was designing a function that creates a struct, and I wondered what would be the most efficient way to do that, even if I don't really need such optimisations.

Comment: Actually this question arised in my mind because I know that it's better to pass a struct by reference, and I wondered if it were also the case for the return value.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the program design. Generally returning (and passing) the whole struct is more costly and it consumes automatic storage duration space which is limited in most implementations.

There is no answer to this question and it depends on your neeeds.

Comment: That is more a "theoretical" question; I don't really have any needs, my current program is quite light and running on my PC so with several Gb of RAM. But as I was designing a function to create a structure, this question arised in my mind.

But based on your answer, it seems that returning the whole struct is less efficient than returning a pointer and has only downsides (excepted perhaps for the simplicity of the writing).

Answer (score 0):

In the select cases where the `struct` is smallish and used to represent a number like the following example ...

```
typedef struct {
  int numerator;
  int denominator;
} fraction.
```

... I find returning a `struct` as in `fraction foo(fraction a, fraction b)` more useful than pointers.  That form mimics the `math.h` library and allows:

```
fraction e = fraction_add(fraction_mul(a, b), fraction_mul(c, d));
```

---

No comment on other cases.